# how to pass key of tabpanel from wiew to controller asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I have a tab panel that allowed me to switch between two window, I'd sent my choice my controller to execute a different statement in each tabuleur, for example if I have id = proj_tab_1 it returns me to input and if id = proj_tab_2 it returns the output view, but I do not know how to pass the spreadsheet key information between the view and controller here is my code

view :

```
 <div class="tab-content">

    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="proj_tab_1" >

        @Html.Partial("_InputFilesList", Model)
    </div>



    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="proj_tab_2" >
        @Html.Partial("_OutputFilesList", Model)
    </div>

</div>
```

controller :

```
  public ActionResult GetFilesListByType(MonitorFilesModel model)
        {
            model.FillDDL();
            model.GetFilesListByType();
            ViewBag.Success = true;

//if tableur 1
                return View("_InputFilesList", "~/Views/Shared/_AjaxLayout.cshtml", model);
            //if tableur 2
            return View("_OutputFilesList", "~/Views/Shared/_AjaxLayout.cshtml", model);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to send key to controller. The easiest way, use javascript (I use jquery but it is up to you), something like that:

```
<script>

 $('dom_element').on('event', function(){

   var rel = $(this);
   var pane = rel.closest('.tab-pane');
   pane.removeClass('in');
   pane.removeClass('active');
   pane.next('.tab-pane').addClass('in active');
 });
</script>
```

Otherwise, you can set your partial views in form and using standard action on submit button redirect to the action you needed.

By the way, I think that you have to return partial view, but not just views.

Hope, it helps.